# Is there any support for NFC tag on Windows Phone emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-8, emulation, nfc

Is there any support for NFC tag on Windows Phone emulator?
I would like to code virtual nfc tag and use it on emulator. Is this possible now?

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Phone Emulator does not have any built-in support for testing Proximity, requiring you test your NFC functionality using a Windows Phone 8 that supports NFC.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207060(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207060%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Yeah I did in past but now I don't have a phone. Thanks.